# filter and sort wordpress get_posts with advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I have two custom fields created with Advanced Custom Fields. 
One is type of checkbox (isEvent) and another is type of date (closing_date).
If I want to get all the posts that are events I would do something like this

```
<?php $args = array(
  'posts_per_page'   => 7,
  'offset'           => 0,
  'category'         => '',
  'category_name'    => '',
  'orderby'          => '',
  'order'            => '',
  'include'          => '', 
  'exclude'          => '',
  'meta_key'         => 'is_event',
  'meta_value'       => 'a:1:{i:0;s:4:"true";}',
  'post_type'        => 'events',
  'post_mime_type'   => '',
  'post_parent'      => '',
  'author'           => '',
  'post_status'      => 'publish',
  'suppress_filters' => 0 
);
$my_posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

And this is working. 
But If I would like to sort by closing_date which is the custom field of type date, in the ACF documentation for sorting is suggested that i should do something like this:

```
<?php $args = array(
  'posts_per_page'   => 7,
  'offset'           => 0,
  'category'         => '',
  'category_name'    => '',
  'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'            => 'asc',
  'include'          => '', 
  'exclude'          => '',
  'meta_key'         => 'closing_date',
  'meta_value'       => '',
  'post_type'        => 'events',
  'post_mime_type'   => '',
  'post_parent'      => '',
  'author'           => '',
  'post_status'      => 'publish',
  'suppress_filters' => 0 
);
$my_posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

This is not working. Update - I managed to get this thing to work. I did not change anything, after few tests it worked....

Can someone give answer on any of these questions (or all)  ?

1. What is the way to have two custom fields in wordpress and you want
   to sort by one and filter by another ?
2. Is this possible in one call of get_posts or is there any other
   native wp technique?
3. Can get_posts have meta_key, meta_value and meta_query in same
   argument list for get_posts?

I also want to add also that I am using the WPML translation plugin with 2 languages en and fr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to write the query is

```
$my_posts_array = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'         => 'events',
        'posts_per_page'    => '7',
        'offset'            => 0,
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters'  => 0,
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'is_event',
                'value'     => 'a:1:{i:0;s:4:"true";}',
                'compare'   => '='
            )
        ),
        'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'closing_date',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        )
    );
```

2.Yes this is possible in one call try above code or if not woeking then try this.

```
$my_posts_array = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => '7',
    'offset'            => 0,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters'  => 0,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'is_event',
            'value'     => 'a:1:{i:0;s:4:"true";}',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    ),
    )
);

// The Loop
foreach ($my_posts_array as $key => $value) {
    $allowed_posts[] = get_the_ID();
}


$sorted_array = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => '7',
    'offset'            => 0,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters'  => 0 ,
    'post__in'          =>  $allowed_posts,
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'          => 'closing_date',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
);

foreach ($sorted_array as $key => $value) {
    //do the stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK,
I managed to answer to this questions by myself.
1. This is one way of doing it:

```
             <?php $args = array(
              'posts_per_page'   => 7,
              'offset'           => 0,
              'category'         => '',
              'category_name'    => '',
              'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
              'order'            => 'ASC',
              'include'          => '', 
              'exclude'          => '',
              'meta_key'         => 'closing_date',
              'meta_value'       => '',
              'post_type'        => 'events',
              'post_mime_type'   => '',
              'post_parent'      => '',
              'author'           => '',
              'post_status'      => 'publish',
              'meta_query' => array(
                            array('key' => 'is_event',
                                  'value' => 'a:1:{i:0;s:4:"true";}'
                            )
                        ),
              'suppress_filters' => 0
            );
            $my_posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

2. I assume you can accomplish this in similar fashion with WP_Query since get_posts i actually using this method.
3.Answer is Yes like in the above example.